# Mysql error when try to update a table from another table

Tags: mysql

I need to update a field in TableA from the same field on TableB

```
UPDATE TableA  
SET TableA.categories = (  
    SELECT TableB.categories  
    FROM TableB  
    WHERE TableB.title = TableA.title
);
```

I get this error :

> Error in query (1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: 'Any ideas about how to fix the script ?' use a join instead of a subquery. refer Multiple-table syntax:here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Comment: Is `TableB.uid` a primary key? Are the values of `TableB` unique?

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The value of `categories` field on TableB are not unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are updating more than one row then subquery will not work, try using JOIN UPDATE

```
UPDATE TableA
JOIN TableB ON TableB.title = TableA.title AND TableB.uid = TableA.uid
SET TableA.categories = TableB.categories;
```

Comment: Works perfect, thank you @Bilal